# Python: Append JSON objects to nested list

Tags: json, python-2.7, list, nested

I'm trying to iterate through a list of IP addresses, and extracting the JSON data from my url, and trying to put that JSON data into a nested list.

It seems as if my code is overwriting my list over and over, and will only show one JSON object, instead of the many I have specified.

Here's my code:

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    try:
        url = 'http://' + ip_addr[x][0] + ':8080/system/ids/'
        response = urlopen(url)
        json_obj = json.load(response)
    except:
        continue

    camera_details = [[i['name'], i['serial']] for i in json_obj['cameras']]

for x in camera_details:
    #This only prints one object, and not 10.
    print x
```

How can I append my JSON objects into a list, and then extract the 'name' and 'serial' values into a nested list?

Comment: Please properly indent your code... Did I fixed it correctly?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes you have, sorry about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
camera_details = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    try:
        url = 'http://' + ip_addr[x][0] + ':8080/system/ids/'
        response = urlopen(url)
        json_obj = json.load(response)
    except:
        continue

    camera_details.extend([[i['name'], i['serial']] for i in json_obj['cameras']])

for x in camera_details:
    print x
```

in your code you where only getting the last requests data

Best would be using append and avoiding list comprehension

```
camera_details = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    try:
        url = 'http://' + ip_addr[x][0] + ':8080/system/ids/'
        response = urlopen(url)
        json_obj = json.load(response)
    except:
        continue
    for i in json_obj['cameras']:
        camera_details.append([i['name'], i['serial']])

for x in camera_details:
    print x
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has seemed to work for me and looking at how it works from this side gives a definite insight into how I should have been interpreting my lists. Awesome, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking up your code into smaller, easier to digest parts. This will help you to diagnose what's going on.

```
camera_details = []
for obj in json_obj['cameras']:
    if 'name' in obj and 'serial' in obj:
        camera_details.append([obj['name'], obj['serial']])
```